# Upload multiple images at windows form application in 1 click

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, database-connection

I am creating a Windows form application in which I have added a button which will open the dialog box and select multiple images, I want to save all the images in the database when I click submit.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Didn't find any answers yet still waiting for it.Let me know if you got any?